# Most Economic Means of Improving Javascript Performance (by supplanting jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, refactoring

Ok, other than purchasing a beast of a machine to improve performance...

I've got a Javascript/AJAX driven web app that was written utilizing jQuery in order to speed up inital development time. I'm finding that from a performance perspective, I'm ready to begin supplanting piece by piece to improve the code efficiency.

One Example...

http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-jquery

I moved away from using **`$(selector).text()`** in active areas to naitive DOM access with **`getElementById(id).innerHTML`**

I'm a little bit at a loss as to where to go next in terms of getting the most bang for my buck, **what are some glaring areas where utilizing jQuery causes you to take a performance hit (outside load times)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/)

1. Use Tags Before Classes
2. Cache jQuery Objects
3. Harness the Power of Chaining
4. Use Sub-queries
5. Limit Direct DOM Manipulation
6. Leverage Event Delegation (a.k.a. Bubbling)
7. Eliminate Query Waste
8. Defer to $(window).load
9. Compress Your JS
10. Learn the Library
11. Always Descend From an #id

These are the key areas, that I always keep in mind when using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Any jquery custom selector, i.e. something that is not native to the browser, will be orders of magnitude slower. so doing

```
$('.sharedclass').find('crappyselector');
```

will speed up long searches.

Also insertion, if you are ever doing insertion in a loop(i.e. a table), build a string first then insert all at once.

Those are the 2 big ones I run into.

Also, profile profile profile. There is no point in fixing something that isn't a problem.

Comment: Also note that `$('div.sharedclass').find('whatever')` (or, if not "div", the appropriate tag) is probably better than just a class name.

Comment: As insert all at once place the subtree in a fragment as described by Ressig in http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: @Pointy Not always!  See my answer and the [JSPerf Proof](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-test)!  The trick is whether or not the browser supports `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @AdamTerlson yes I'm sure that's true - it's why I wrote "probably" :-)

Comment: @AdamTerlson ... although there's not much to that DOM - a really big DOM with *lots* of content and a class that's really spread among different element types (possibly a fishy practice, admittedly) might be an interesting test too.

Comment: @Pointy Very true, but at that point what are you testing it against?  There'd be really no options *but* just doing `$('.foo')` as your ID context would be substantially broad anyway, right?

Comment: @AdamTerlson yes I suppose so - if you really want only `<em>` tags with class "foo" I guess you have no choice anyway, really; it'd be interesting to see how `$('.foo').is('em')` compares to `$('em.foo')` :-)

Comment: @Pointy You're just trying to get me to write the jsperf script for you, aren't you?  Jerk... *sigh* One second.

Comment: Ha ha no, just thinking out loud. But go for it if I've piqued your curiosity!

Comment: @Pointy Not sure how valid my test is for what you were thinking, but here you go: http://jsperf.com/class-test/2

Answer (score 1):

Try other frameworks. See this comparison where DOJO wins:
http://blog.creonfx.com/javascript/dojo-vs-jquery-vs-mootools-vs-prototype-performance-comparison
I like all the pointers given above and found Jose Vega's to work well.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` loops, where the loop is particularly large. If it's small, the difference is negligible, but the performance of a traditional JavaScript for loop is much better, particularly when dealing with large amounts of data.

Also, it's not specifically what you asked for - but revisit all your selectors when utilizing **events**, particularly for IE which has no support for "`getElementsByClassName`" (Lots of other browsers do) and prefix any class names used in event wire-ups with an ID, where possible. I found this improved IE performance, particularly when combined with removing context-less pseudo-selectors like `$(":input")`

e.g.

```
$(".etc").live("click", function() { } );
```

becomes

```
$("#id").delegate(".etc", "click", function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just based off of other folk's answers I thought I'd throw in my own two-cents on an often-quoted one.  Beware browser differences in selector performance!  What you think might always be fastest isn't always true!

Safest selector is of course `$('#foo')`, but consider the following:

`$('.bar')` is faster than `$('#foo .bar')` and `$('#foo').find('.bar')` in browsers that natively support `getElementsByClassName()`.  In fact, much faster (more than twice as fast in FF and basically every browser but IE).

For proof, see [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-test).

You might be able to do some browser-specific selector optimization.